# Different action bar for each fragment in Android - best approach?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I am building an Android project with lots of fragments that each have different action bars.

The recommended approach I've seen is to use a main layout that includes the toolbar, and then each fragment interacts with the action bar of the main layout.

To me, it seems to make more sense to just include a different toolbar separately in each fragment layout, but this goes against the approach that I see recommended everywhere. In fact, I find it quite messy to change the action bar attributes each time the fragment is started (the fragments are kept in memory). Are there any downsides to including a toolbar in each fragment individually?

Answer (score 0):

In a project I'm working on I have just one main action bar for every fragment, and every time the user switches to another fragment I change the properties of it basing on the fragment id, to me this is the cleanest and most simple solution.